# What's the difference between a "debug interrupt" and int 80h?

Tags: assembly, x86

This is a question from a test. The possible answers were:

```
(a) Debug interrupt is always caused by an error, and int 80h isn't.
(b) Only on int 80h the returning address is saved.
(c) int 80h is always caused by an error and debug interrupt isn't.
(d) None of the above.
```

The only thing I'm positive about is that (c) is wrong.

Could anyone shed some light on the differences among the two?

Comment: I don't know what a "debug interrupt" is, there isn't a standard meaning for that term that I'm aware of. And what `int 80h` does is operating system specific.

Comment: I'm guessing by "debug interrupt", OP means `int 3h`. Also, I can assure you that (b) is also wrong, since *any* interrupt saves the return address

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: It could also be referring `int 1`, or to an exception interrupt such as a page fault or divide by zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Debug interrupt is always caused by an error, and int 80h isn't

Debug interrupts are almost always intentionally inserted in the code.  Either with inline assembly, an intrinsic in the code (like __debugbreak) or by the debugger to get the processor to invoke a debug break when it lands on the start of a statement.  Strongly enabled by the way an int 03h is encoded on x86 and x64 processors, it is an instruction that takes a single byte (CCh) so is very easy to insert by a debugger.  INTO is the other oddball, the rest take two bytes.  Nothing to do with an error, so no.

> Only on int 80h the returning address is saved

The processor treats all software interrupts the same way, the interrupt number merely selects the interrupt handler.  Int 03h also stores the return address on the stack, so no.

> int 80h is always caused by an error and debug interrupt isn't

It entirely depends on the operating system what an int 80h might do.  But this almost certainly refers to Linux, it uses int 80h to transition into kernel mode to call a low-level operating system function.  Those are not errors of course, so no.

Which leaves (d) None of the above.